# Remove duplicate entries in parse-server

Tags: javascript, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

Parse-server doesn't support `groupBy` for queries. So instead of adapting code to work with the duplicate entries i've decided to create a Job to clean the data.

[image]

I've created a cloud function using `underscore` but the results are not good. It's deleting non-duplicate entries too.

I want to remove a entry if another entry exists with the same `post_id` and `user_id`

```
    Parse.Cloud.job("removeDuplicateItems", function(request, status) {
     var _ = require("underscore");
     var hashTable = {};

      function hashKeyForTestItem(testItem) {
        var fields = ["user_id", "post_id"];
        var hashKey = "";
        _.each(fields, function (field) {
            hashKey += testItem.get(field) + "/" ;
        });
        return hashKey;
      }

      var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query("Post_shares");
      testItemsQuery.each(function (testItem) {
        var key = hashKeyForTestItem(testItem);

        if (key in hashTable) { // this item was seen before, so destroy this
            return testItem.destroy();
        } else { // it is not in the hashTable, so keep it
            hashTable[key] = 1;
        }

      }).then(function() {
        status.success("removal completed successfully.");
      }, function(error) {
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
      });
    });
```

Is there a better way of doing this?